# Has THIS day and time passed THIS week or not - PHP

Tags: php, time

I have 3 variables for a day and time of the week stored in an array :

```
$shift['day'];
$shift['hour'];
$shift['meridian'];
```

All 3 together, respectively output something like :

```
Friday 10 PM
```

DATE is not being used at all, just DAY and TIME and it's obviously not stored as a timestamp.

How can I check if this DAY and TIME has already passed THIS week?

So for example :

```
$today = date("l"); // Get current day "Monday"
$hour = date("g"); // Get current hour "3"
$meridian = date("A"); // Get current meridian "PM"
```

Will get me the current values ready to compare to my variables but I'm lost at how the logic would work to determine if my time has already passed this week or not?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are better off using Javascript for this.  PHP only runs on the server.  Since that can be anywhere in the world, you'll need adjustments for timezones.  Which is just another can of worms.

Comment: Get the numeric value of the day. `N`. Probably better off using 24 hour clock than `meridian`.

Comment: @durbnpoisn No it's fine, I can do this with PHP as the output will be strictly server related (not user / browser / timezone). I just need to know the logic.

Comment: @chris85 I agree, but it's not possible without a whole bunch of conversions on my original vars. I have an entire database that's been set up using this method. I can do it if it makes the logic to work it all out easier though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `date` functions to get the values down to integers then just use a conditional.

```
$shift['day'] = 'Friday';
$shift['meridian'] = 'PM';
$hour = '10';
$shift['hour'] = ($shift['meridian'] == 'PM') ? $hour + 12 : $hour; //convert input to 24 hour
$today = date("N");
$current_hour = date("G");
if( date('N', strtotime($shift['day'])) <= $today &&  $current_hour <= $shift['hour']) {
    echo 'It hasn\'t occurred yet this week';
} else {
    echo 'It has occurreced this week';
}
```

... or as a one liner (assuming `$shift['hour']` is 24 hours):

```
if( date('N', strtotime($shift['day'])) <=  date("N") &&  date("G") <= $shift['hour']) {
```

Demo: https://eval.in/542298

Make sure you have the timezone set correctly otherwise where midnight falls could throw off the day.

Answer (score 2):

Logic:

- Create `DateTime` object for now
- Create `DateTime` object for `Friday 10 PM`.
- Compare them by timestamps to see which one is larger

Code:

```
$tz = new \DateTimeZone("UTC");
$now = new \DateTime("now", $tz);
$then = \DateTime::createFromFormat('l g A', 'Friday 10 PM', $tz);

if($then->getTimestamp() < $now->getTimestamp())
{
    echo 'Friday 10 PM has passed this week';
}
else
{
    echo 'No, Friday 10 PM has not passed this week';
}
```

Echoing `$then->format('d.m.Y, H:i:s')` yields `25.03.2016, 22:00:00`.
Changing the day from "Friday" to "Saturday" correctly yields 26th of March, which is what I used to verify that the `DateTime` object is created correctly for given string (`Friday 10 PM`).

Comment: Actually after toying with the other answers here, this one turns out to be the only one that is the most reliable. The DateTime API is something that I hadn't used before, but I will be using this for everything date related from now on. Thank you so much Mjh, this is fantastic!

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful, good luck to you with your project and have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 2):

The [DateTime](https://secure.php.net/datetime) class provides a lot of tools to help in doing this, and [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36222089/468027) already utilizes it, but it's biggest advantage by far is that it actually allows you to work with dates in a purely *human* way - you don't have to feed it made-up numbers that just happen to make mathematical sense!

So here's one way to do that ...

Obviously, we need to create the timestamps to compare first:

```
// With no arguments, this is just the current timestamp
$now = DateTime();

// Tricky part here is to know that any omitted *calendar-type* values
// default to the current day, while *time* values default to 0s
$shift = DateTime::createFromFormat(
    'l g A',
    "{$shift['day']} {$shift['hour']} {$shift['meridian']}"
);
```

But what is hard to spot (at least at the time I'm writing this) in the PHP manual for `DateTime` class is the [DateTime::diff() method](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) which actually only appears on the TOC for `DateTimeInterface`.
Once you have that, you only need to know that `+` and `-` signs mean "future" and "past":

```
if ($now->diff($shift)->format('%R') === '-')
{
    // $shift is in the past; i.e. Friday 10 PM has passed
}
```

---

Of course you can replicate the same thing via `date()`, `strtotime()` and math, but this is way more expressive and easily understandable.

Comment: That is super slick! ;)